# Непонятное поведение BitmapFactory

Tags: android, bitmap

Код очень простой:

`BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
 options.inSampleSize = 1;
 options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
 options.inScaled = false;
 options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
 sourceBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.eumap, options);`

На выходе имеем битмап 3000х2000 размером около 24 мб (проверяю через `sourceBitmap.getByteCount()`). Далее меняю `options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565` и получаю картинку 12мб. Всё пока логично. Но когда указываю `Bitmap.Config.ALPHA_8`, получаю ЦВЕТНУЮ картинку размером 6мб! Проверял как рисованием битмапа,  так и выборочные пиксели, цвет есть. В то же время `BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.eumap, options).extractAlpha()` даёт ожидаемый результат, черную картинку размером 6мб. Как это можно объяснить?